# What causes a ssh interruption?

Tags: ssh, putty

What exactly causes a ssh connection to interrupt? When you idle for a while, it disconnects.

How do I keep the connection alive (without `autossh` or reconnect)?

Answer (score 11):

This is most likely a firewall which cuts your idle connection after a while.

You can configure the `openssh` server or client to send a KeepAlive after a while.

Send a KeepAlive every 5 minutes to the server:

```
ssh user@server -o ServerAliveInterval=300
```

If you have control over the `openssh-server`, you can also send KeepAlives to the client after a defined interval. Add the following to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
ClientAliveInterval 300
TCPKeepAlive yes
```

`TCPKeepAlive` should be `yes` by default.

Restart the `openssh-server` after the modification:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh restart
```

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few things you can try:

1) It's most likely the shell which is timing out. Disable the timeout by unsetting `TMOUT` in your profile. `TMOUT` is the number of seconds that bash waits for input before terminating. Echo `$TMOUT` to see if it is set. Add the following to your profile:

```
unset TMOUT
```

2) Configure PuTTY to send keepalive packets by going into:

```
Settings > Connection > Seconds between keepalives = 60
```

3) Tweak your `sshd_config` (normally found in `/etc/ssh`) and add:

```
TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 60
```

Save the file and restart `sshd`.

Comment: in theory this should always make the connection established? i will try `ClientAliveInterval`

Comment: This works great!!!! havn't disconnected for 24 hours, where normally breaks every hour.

Comment: Adding `ClientAliveCountMax 1440` will allow the connection to time out after 1440 minute checks (1 day). You can adjust this to extend the timeout but not disable it completely.